# explicit jquery indexOf()

Tags: javascript

lets say I have a string with ids from a database:

```
    string = "3, 4, 5, 8, 16, 2, 43"
```

and numbers from some checkbox values what I map into an array

```
    filter = ["35", "34"]
```

I want to compare if ALL numbers from the array are part of the string, so I tried something like this (what works a bit)

```
    if ( string.indexOf(filter) !== -1 )
    { console.log("numbers of filter are in string") }
```

but my problem is that of cause the 3 is in 34 - so `indexOf` is true. Any idea how I have to compare this "the right way" ?

Comment: This is **pure** javascript. Theres no *jquery* or *jscript* used here.

Comment: If your string is array-like (like it seems to be) why not just split it by `,` and you can do a proper comparison with your `filter` array

Comment: @tony that would be a good answer, wouldnt it? ;)

Comment: but jonas, javascript = jscript or ?   and of cause i wanted to say / signal that my complete script includes jquery, and that i am not affraid of a jquery solution.

Comment: @scco no, why should there be two tags for one thing?

Comment: "javascript = jscript"  no, it most certainly is not.

Comment: ok, whow i didnt even know that. how to find out if i code in jscript or javascript :p

Comment: @scco you code in javascript. I bet.

Answer (score 2):

My example. Hope it helps

```
const str = "23, 4, 567, 7",
      firstArr = ["1", "3", "4"],
      secondArr = str.split(", ");

if(secondArr.filter(e => firstArr.indexOf(e) !== -1).length > 0) {
    console.log('str has some numbers from the firstArr');
}
```

Comment: @Jonas no reason not to, as long as it makes the final answer better.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add a whitespace in front:

```
const string = " 3, 4, 5, 8, 16, 2, 43",
    filters = ["35", "34"];

if(filters.every( filter => string.includes(" "+filter))){
  alert(" all found!");
}
```

Or you build a real array out of the string:

```
const string = "3, 4, 5, 8, 16, 2, 43",
    filters = ["35", "34"];

const ids = string.split(", ");

if(filters.every( filter => ids.includes(filter))) 
   alert(" all found!");
```

Comment: for some reason i get parse errors on minify / uglify that ( using codekit for mac ) . but i agree its better to convert the string to an array. hope i can find some other method to compare these both arrays now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
string.includes(filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string to an array and check the values from there

```js
string = "3, 4, 5, 8, 16, 2, 43";
stringarray = string.split(', ');


filter = ["35", "34"];
containsall = filter.every(elem => stringarray.indexOf(elem) > -1);
alert(containsall);


filter2 = ["3", "16"];
containsall = filter2.every(elem => stringarray.indexOf(elem) > -1);
alert(containsall);
```

Comment: for some reason i get parse errors on minify / uglify that ( using codekit for mac ) . but i agree its better to convert the string to an array. hope i can find some other method to compare these both arrays now.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
var string =  "3,4,5,8,16,2,43";
var filter = ["32", "42"];
var filter1 = ["3", "4"];

var stringArr = string.split(',');

var result = filter.every(function(val) { return stringArr.indexOf(val) >= 0; });
var result1 = filter1.every(function(val) { return stringArr.indexOf(val) >= 0; });

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
```

Comment: for some reason i get parse errors on minify / uglify that ( using codekit for mac ) . but i agree its better to convert the string to an array. hope i can find some other method to compare these both arrays now.

Comment: crazy. now it works. no idea why i got this  minify problems. thanks sudhir!